# Which content-type to use when Uploading sqlite .db file to a server?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to upload a .db (SQLite) file from my android app to a server and I'm wondering if I can use "multipart/form-data" as the content-type. Is there any specific type for .db file as for pdf files which is "application/pdf" ?

Comment: "multipart/form-data" is used for HTML forms. Did you read the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type)?

Comment: yes I did read the wikipedia page, However the [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt)  states that it can also be used for non HTML forms such as spreadsheet, pdf,etc.

Comment: But then you would have to embed the file into the multipart structure.

Comment: @CL. Thanks for your input. I got it working now.

Comment: @YassineHoussni  Why did you down vote my question? Moreover you pretended as if you edited my question meanwhile you didn't add any value to it. Is it because your solution didn't work out for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got it working with just the "multipart/form-data" as the content type. When I tried the 'application/x-sqlite3', I had an error.

Here is the code snippet I used to post the .db file to server, borrowed from this [link](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83):

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    String fileName = sourceFileUri; // the path to my .db file

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist ");
        return 0;
    } else {
        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true); //Triggers  http POST method.

            connection.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
            //conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-sqlite3; boundary=" + boundary);// when I tried this it didn't work, so you can delete this line
            connection.setRequestProperty("uploadedfile", fileName);

            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=" + fileName + "" + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                String msg = "server respose code ";
                Log.i(TAG, msg + serverResponseCode);
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                //JSONObject mResponseJSONObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(result)); //convert the respons in json
                Log.i(TAG, msg + result);
            }

            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Upload file to server Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return serverResponseCode;

    } // End else block
} //[End uploadFileToServer method]
```

This is php script I used on the server side:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES)) {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"],  "./data/".$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]."_".time())) {

            echo " file recieved successfully"
            exit;
    }
}
echo "Error";

?>
```